# use grpc in nodejs and typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, grpc

i need to use GRPC in nodejs an type script project , i have a problem with generate proto files in windows 10 and npm .

i want to ru this file `transpile-proto-ts.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

OUT_DIR="./src"
TS_OUT_DIR="./src"
IN_DIR="./protos"
PROTOC="$(npm bin)/grpc_tools_node_protoc"
PROTOC_GEN_TS_PATH="$(npm bin)/protoc-gen-ts"
PROTOC_GEN_GRPC_PATH="$(npm bin)/grpc_tools_node_protoc_plugin"

$PROTOC \
    -I="./" \
    --plugin=protoc-gen-ts=$PROTOC_GEN_TS_PATH \
    --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=${PROTOC_GEN_GRPC_PATH} \
    --js_out=import_style=commonjs:$OUT_DIR \
    --grpc_out=grpc_js:$OUT_DIR \
    --ts_out=grpc_js:$TS_OUT_DIR \
    "$IN_DIR"/*.proto
```

but when i run this command in `git bash` : `bash transpile-proto-ts.sh`

it show me this error :

```
>--ts_out: protoc-gen-ts: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

C:\Projects\GRPC\node_modules\grpc-tools\bin\protoc.js:41
    throw error;
    ^

Error: Command failed: C:\Projects\GRPC\node_modules\grpc-tools\bin\protoc.exe --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=C:\Projects\GRPC\node_modules\grpc-tools\bin\grpc_node_plugin.exe --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=./node_modules/.bin/grpc_tools_node_protoc_plugin --plugin=protoc-gen-ts=./node_modules/.bin/protoc-gen-ts --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:./protos --ts_out=./protos --grpc_out=./protos -I ./protos ./protos/example.proto
--ts_out: protoc-gen-ts: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.


    at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:397:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5) {
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'C:\\Projects\\GRPC\\node_modules\\grpc-tools\\bin\\protoc.exe --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=C:\\Projects\\GRPC\\node_modules\\grpc-tools\\bin\\grpc_node_plugin.exe --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=./node_modules/.bin/grpc_tools_node_protoc_plugin --plugin=protoc-gen-ts=./node_modules/.bin/protoc-gen-ts --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:./protos --ts_out=./protos --grpc_out=./protos -I ./protos ./protos/example.proto'
}
```

Comment: How did you install the protoc-gen-ts plugin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your sh file is executable as

```
chmod 777 transpile-proto-ts.sh
```

I had a similar issue and I used YARN instead of NPM.